# R Package ISO Week Returning incorrect values compared to ISO 8601 in Spotfire

Tags: r, spotfire, iso, terr

Following this article, I am using the ISOWeek "R" package in Tibco Spotfire to return the ISOWeek for a specific date.

https://community.tibco.com/wiki/tibco-spotfirer-tips-tricks-reusable-simple-easy-iso-week-calculation-spotfire

According to all websites, 01-Dec-2019 is Week 48.  This day is a Sunday, and ISO 8601 assumes a week starts on a Monday.

https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2019

However, the TERR function in Spotfire, when passed the date 01-Dec-2019 returns week 49...almost as if it is making Sunday the start day of the week, in complete contradiction to ISO 8601.

This is the Spotfire output.

[image: e]

Answer (score 0):

This indeed looks like a bug. A more reliable solution might be to use [strftime](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime):

```
strftime("2019-12-1", "%U")
> "48"
```

Comment: Thanks - this works in Spotfire client, but still giving the wrong result in the web player!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spotfire. Does the web player run on your machine? I think this is down to the locale settings under which the web player operates. The environment variable `LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"` should be set. This setting includes that weeks start with Monday.

Comment: If 8601 requires a week to start on a Monday, why would it require a setting to make it work?  Surely a function to calculate the ISO Week shouldn’t give different results across environments?

Comment: That's why I thought it looks like a bug. Anyway, I tried it on my own system (Lubuntu 18.04, R 3.6.2, ISOweek 0.6-2) and it gave the result you expected (48). What system are you running on?

Comment: Client is running Windows 10, not sure about the web server when not working locally...

Comment: You can find out the OS that the server is running by executing `.Platform` and checking the field `OS.type` in the output.

Comment: BTW, did `strftime` return the correct output for you?

Comment: Hi, it did on my client - but not on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `format()` with `%V`, i.e.,

```
d <- as.Date(c("2019-12-01","2019-12-17"))
w <- format(d,"%V")
```

such that

```
> w
[1] "48" "51"
```